# iOS. Two versions of the same program are mixing when i compile first version after the second one

Tags: iphone, ios, version-control, version

I use xCode 4.0.2, an iPhone 3 (device) with jailbreak (iOS 4.2.1), mac os 10.6.8 (not an apple computer).
I have 2 versions of my software: 0_10 and 0_11 (the second one was received by copying the folder of the first one, then I changed the folder name and make some additional code for it).
Through some time i have found out that i cannot put the text into a textfield in the second version (i still dont know why). If I fully delete the first version and then install the second one then textField in second version doesnt work. If I hadn't done this before my second version shows some signs of the first one (and even textField can work).

So the question is how to evade this version mixing? Maybe is anybody know how to automate the full deleting of the program from a device without of doing this manually?

Answer (score 0):

if this is just for testing purposes then just change the bundle identifier in one of the project's info.plist file. This will install the different versions as two separate apps, although i have no experience with jail broken devices so I'm not sure if there will be any conflicts.